# Mercurial always says file was updated when changing branch

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch

I am using Mercurial `3.1.2` on Linux. I have 2 brances: `default` and `stable`.

Always when I change branch I see notice saying that file was updated altough as far as I know the branches should be in the same state. (I just merged and committed them before running `hg up`.)

```
hg up default
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

I cannot see any difference by using `hg diff`.

```
hg diff -r default:stable
(empty result)
```

This is completely local project, I don't push or pull anywhere.

How can I find out what file is changing when I switch branch and what is the difference?
Shouldn't merging branches have eliminated any difference between them?

Update: I took checksums of all files belonging to the project in both `stable` and `default` and there was no difference between branches.

Then I run command `ls -l` in both branches and took diff of results:

```
- -rw-r--r--  1 user group  16K Sep  2 12:04 Program.py
+ -rw-r--r--  1 user group  16K Sep  2 12:05 Program.py
```

One file of project has different modification time between branches.

Comment: modification time is part of the state... though it should be updated when you update to the different version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get rid of this message by merging from stable to default.
(Normally I merge from default to stable only.)

Diff of this merge is empty but now Mercurial only reports files changed if there are real changes.